# Flexible diamond grid with images that are already diamonds

Tags: html, css

I've found many methods of creating a flexible diamond grid online, but I'm just at a loss on how to adapt them. My case is a bit odd. First, the images in my case are already 92x93px diamonds so I don't need HTML codes for `transform: rotate` and inner text adjustments etc, and I need the top of the grid to have fewer diamonds than the lower rows. Obviously, in order to flex, I need the images to shrink and the box they are into shrink as well.

So here is the original code I currently have from years ago before I tried to improve it and failed completely. Each CCi is a 92x93px image. Here is an example of an image used in the code: https://gamepedia.cursecdn.com/onehundredpercentorangejuice_gamepedia_en/d/d6/Syura.png?version=67384f8f95f86dc78fe9e1b6636bd0ff 
and the awful code:

```
<div class="boxcoloring" style="width:786px; height:578px; margin: auto; -moz-border-radius: .7em; -webkit-border-radius: .7em; border-radius: .7em;">
<div class="hoverimage" style="position:relative; width:10em; height:16em;">
<span style="position:absolute; left:60px;  top:2px;  ">{{CCi|QP (Dangerous)}}</span>
<span style="position:absolute; left:172px; top:2px;  ">{{CCi|Tomato & Mimyuu}}</span>
<span style="position:absolute; left:284px; top:2px;  ">{{CCi|Ceoreparque}}</span>
<span style="position:absolute; left:396px; top:2px;  ">{{CCi|Miusaki}}</span>
<span style="position:absolute; left:508px; top:2px;  ">{{CCi|Yuki (Dangerous)}}</span>
<span style="position:absolute; left:620px; top:2px;  ">{{CCi|Yuuki}}</span>
<span style="position:absolute; left:4px;   top:60px; ">{{CCi|Suguri (Ver.2)}}</span>
<span style="position:absolute; left:116px; top:60px; ">{{CCi|QP}}</span>
<span style="position:absolute; left:228px; top:60px; ">{{CCi|Store Manager}}</span>
<span style="position:absolute; left:340px; top:60px; ">{{CCi|Sweet Breaker}}</span>
<span style="position:absolute; left:452px; top:60px; ">{{CCi|Syura}}</span>
<span style="position:absolute; left:564px; top:60px; ">{{CCi|Yuki}}</span>
<span style="position:absolute; left:676px; top:60px; ">{{CCi|Sora & Sham (Cuties)}}</span>
<span style="position:absolute; left:60px;  top:118px;">{{CCi|Suguri}}</span>
<span style="position:absolute; left:172px; top:118px;">{{CCi|Kyousuke}}</span>
<span style="position:absolute; left:284px; top:118px;">{{CCi|Mei}}</span>
<span style="position:absolute; left:396px; top:118px;">{{CCi|Natsumi}}</span>
<span style="position:absolute; left:508px; top:118px;">{{CCi|Nico}}</span>
<span style="position:absolute; left:620px; top:118px;">{{CCi|Star Breaker}}</span>
<span style="position:absolute; left:4px;   top:176px;">{{CCi|Shifu Robot}}</span>
<span style="position:absolute; left:116px; top:176px;">{{CCi|Saki}}</span>
<span style="position:absolute; left:228px; top:176px;">{{CCi|Chicken}}</span>
<span style="position:absolute; left:340px; top:176px;">{{CCi|Kiriko}}</span>
<span style="position:absolute; left:452px; top:176px;">{{CCi|Krila}}</span>
<span style="position:absolute; left:564px; top:176px;">{{CCi|Sora}}</span>
<span style="position:absolute; left:676px; top:176px;">{{CCi|Tsih}}</span>
<span style="position:absolute; left:60px;  top:234px;">{{CCi|Robo Ball}}</span>
<span style="position:absolute; left:172px; top:234px;">{{CCi|NoName}}</span>
<span style="position:absolute; left:284px; top:234px;">{{CCi|Aru (Scramble)}}</span>
<span style="position:absolute; left:396px; top:234px;">{{CCi|Arthur}}</span>
<span style="position:absolute; left:508px; top:234px;">{{CCi|Nath}}</span>
<span style="position:absolute; left:620px; top:234px;">{{CCi|Sora (Military)}}</span>
<span style="position:absolute; left:116px; top:292px;">{{CCi|Nanako}}</span>
<span style="position:absolute; left:228px; top:292px;">{{CCi|Kyoko}}</span>
<span style="position:absolute; left:340px; top:292px;">{{CCi|Aru}}</span>
<span style="position:absolute; left:452px; top:292px;">{{CCi|Mira}}</span>
<span style="position:absolute; left:564px; top:292px;">{{CCi|Sham}}</span>
<span style="position:absolute; left:676px; top:292px;">{{CCi|Islay}}</span>
<span style="position:absolute; left:60px;  top:350px;">{{CCi|Tomomo}}</span>
<span style="position:absolute; left:172px; top:350px;">{{CCi|Kae}}</span>
<span style="position:absolute; left:284px; top:350px;">{{CCi|Iru}}</span>
<span style="position:absolute; left:396px; top:350px;">{{CCi|Alte}}</span>
<span style="position:absolute; left:508px; top:350px;">{{CCi|Marc}}</span>
<span style="position:absolute; left:620px; top:350px;">{{CCi|Sherry}}</span>
<span style="position:absolute; left:4px;   top:408px;">{{CCi|Tomomo (Casual & Sweet Eater)}}</span>
<span style="position:absolute; left:116px; top:408px;">{{CCi|Marie Poppo}}</span>
<span style="position:absolute; left:228px; top:408px;">{{CCi|Hime}}</span>
<span style="position:absolute; left:340px; top:408px;">[[File:Center_Select.png|link=http://onehundredpercentorangejuice.gamepedia.com/Special:RandomInCategory/Unlockable_Characters|Random Character]]</span>
<span style="position:absolute; left:452px; top:408px;">{{CCi|Fernet}}</span>
<span style="position:absolute; left:564px; top:408px;">{{CCi|Peat}}</span>
<span style="position:absolute; left:676px; top:408px;">{{CCi|Tequila}}</span>
<span style="position:absolute; left:60px;  top:466px;">{{CCi|Marie Poppo (Mixed)}}</span>
<span style="position:absolute; left:172px; top:466px;">{{CCi|Kai}}</span>
<span style="position:absolute; left:284px; top:466px;">[[File:Center_Select.png|link=http://onehundredpercentorangejuice.gamepedia.com/Special:RandomInCategory/Bonus_Characters|Random Character]]</span>
<span style="position:absolute; left:396px; top:466px;">[[File:Center_Select.png|link=http://onehundredpercentorangejuice.gamepedia.com/Special:RandomInCategory/DLC_Characters|Random Character]]</span>
<span style="position:absolute; left:508px; top:466px;">{{CCi|Flying Castle}}</span>
<span style="position:absolute; left:620px; top:466px;">{{CCi|Seagull}}</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Yes, its a terrible terrible way to code, it doesn't flex, and it is difficult to adapt. The ouput looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/geX4R.jpg Currently I can force it to flex by making the first div style have a `display:flex;` and then using things `@media screen and (max-width: 1462px)` in CSS to shrink the images but its just a really crappy way to do it and doesn't work for all flex sizes.

In short, its a very tall order but can someone please provide a way/explanation so I can rebuild this using something like: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JoproP The moment I try to adjust most of the diamond codes I have found, to try to figure out how they work, they just kinda...implode because diamond grids seem rather temperamental with respect to margins and whatnot. Any gentle advice/help would be greatly appreciated. I really just want to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this

HTML

[image]
       [image]
       [image]
       [image]
       [image]
       [image]
       [image]
    
    
       [image]
       [image]
       [image]
       [image]
       [image]
       [image]
       [image]
    
    
       [image]
       [image]
       [image]
       [image]
       [image]
       [image]
       [image]

CSS

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.flex-container > div {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.flex-container:not(:first-child){
  margin-top: -80px;
}
.flex-container.s-row{
  margin-left: 60px;
}
```

Comment: This code makes me the closest I've ever been, but, it's not quite what I need. It has any easy to define issue, however. Using your code I was able to build this which is very very close to what I am looking for: https://codepen.io/The-Greenest-Horn/pen/vYYJxQZ The issue is that I want it to retain its formatting as you shrink it, which it does not. This also makes me unable to use margins because when you shrink the box the px value throws images too high because flex does not like margins. I'm curious if perhaps a calculation would work better: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JoproP